# Python NameError: name is not defined problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

When I run this code showed an error.  I have made some changes in the code for scraping two or more dates in football.  I have use `webdriver` but when the while end it showed an error.  First I inserted the link, second I inserted the date for example 2010-2014 but when I finished the process I have this error:

```
Error NameError: name 'url_list' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep

from urllib.parse import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def get_urls_season(url_path):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    driver.get("https://us.soccerway.com" + url_path)
    click_privacy_policy(driver)
    date = date_selector(driver)
        #url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
    url_list.reverse()
    driver.quit()

    print("=" * 100)
    print(f"{len(set(url_list))} find")

    if input("con? (y/n): ") != "y":
        exit()

    return url_list
def date_selector(driver):
    inptdate=''
    startdate=inptdate.split('-')[0]
    enddate=inptdate.split('-')[1]

    while int(startdate)< int(enddate):
        textstring=str(startdate) + "/" + str(int(startdate)+1)
        print(textstring)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text()='" + textstring +"']").click()
        startdate=int(startdate)+1
        url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)

def click_privacy_policy(driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("qc-cmp-button").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass


def cycle_through_game_weeks(driver):
    season_urls = get_fixture_urls(innerhtml_soup(driver))

    while is_previous_button_enabled(driver):
        click_previous_button(driver)
        sleep(2)

        urls = get_fixture_urls(innerhtml_soup(driver))


        urls.reverse()
        season_urls += urls

    return season_urls


def is_previous_button_enabled(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_id(
        "page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5_previous"
    ).get_attribute("class") != "previous disabled"


def click_previous_button(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_id(
        "page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5_previous"
    ).click()


def get_fixture_urls(soup):

    urls = []
    for elem in soup.select(".info-button.button > a"):
        urls.append(urlparse(elem.get("href")).path)
    return urls


def innerhtml_soup(driver):

    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

I need to solve this problem: `NameError: name  is not defined` problem.

Comment: Uncomment the line where you have `#url_list = cycle...`. There are also a lot of implicit returns in your code. You should probably change all your functions to return explicitly. Also, you probably shouldn't `exit` in the middle of your `get_urls_season` function because it makes the behaviour of your function inconsistent. Return something sensible instead.

Comment: Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please because i need for tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You (or someone) commented out a code line:

```
#url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
```

If this is commented out, the variable does not get set, but the next line:

```
url_list.reverse()
```

is trying to use the variable.

How about uncommenting the first line?  Why has it been commented out in the first place?

Comment: i have insert in  def_selector the url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)